Update react component in response to window object change
I have a component that I need to hide if the user has an ad blocker.
I also have an ad blocker tool that places a piece of data on the window object. So, something like this ...
window.myEvents = [{event:pageLoaded}, {event:adBlockerFound}]

I can't access this tool from the component that I am working on, so I am looking at monitoring the window object until an adBlockerFound event is seen or a noAdBLocker event is seen.
I don't think that you can do this with a standard eventListener.
